# Facebook apps redirecting "via {APP_NAME}" to an existing pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-stream-story

I created an app on Facebook.
Thanks to this app, the users can publish on their wall. All works fine, but I would like to specify an url to redirect to when the user click on the link "via {APP_NAME}" on a publication. For the moment, it's redirecting to https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=APP_ID

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Link with text "via Application Name" that appear aside of stories published by applications lead to:

- Application Canvas URL - if Application have Canvas URL configured in application settings
- Application Site URL - if Application have Site (but not Canvas) URL configured
- Application Profile Page - if Application have regular Facebook Page associated with application and doesn't have Canvas URL specified in application settings
- Application Page - if neither Page associated with Application or Canvas/Site URL is defined

You cannot make this link to point to completely different URL.

If you still need a redirection to resource other than outlined above you can configure Application Site/Canvas URL and do redirection from there once users land to your Application with `fb_source` parameter specified.

`fb_source` may contain different values so you can decide if you want to do a redirection, it's not documented in complete way but there are some examples:

[*Like Button documentation*](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/):

> `fb_source` - the stream type ('home', 'profile', 'search', 'ticker', 'tickerdialog' or 'other') in which the click occurred and the story type ('oneline' or 'multiline'), concatenated with an underscore.

[*Send Button documentation*](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/):

> `fb_source` - the story type ('message', 'group', 'email') in which the click occurred.

`fb_source` may be also `feed` (and probably more values that documented elsewhere or not documented at all).

Comment: How do you set it to the Application Site URL or any of the four choices above?